# VBA Check Row For Value Then Another Value and Paste If True

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of parts numbers with short descriptions and long descriptions. The list is formatted in such a way that in the first column there is a part number. In the second column there is a description code. In the third column there is a description. The description is either the name, short description, or long description based on the preceding description code.

See screenshot example:
[Original Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eVQK.png)

As you can see, some of the parts have all three descriptions and some of them don't.

I'm trying to take the data from sheet 1 and paste the information into sheet 2 that has the consolidated and proper row structure ie. part number, name, short, long.

See screenshot example: [New Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sywAV.png)

Here is some code I've been working with. I feel like I'm close or at least on the right track but it definitely isn't working and currently throwing a next without for error.

```
Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To Rows.Count
With ActiveWorkbook
.Sheets("Parts List").Range("A1").Select
    If .Sheets("Parts List").Cells(i, 1).Value = .Sheets("Product Description").Cells(i, 1) Then
    If .Sheets("Product Description").Cells(i, 2).Value = "DES" Then
    .Sheets("Parts List").Cells(i, 2).Value = .Sheets("Product Description").Cells(i, 2).Value
    ElseIf .Sheets("Product Description").Cells(i, 2).Value = "EXT" Then
    .Sheets("Parts List").Cells(i, 5).Value = .Sheets("Product Description").Cells(i, 2).Value
    ElseIf .Sheets("Product Description").Cells(i, 2).Value = "MKT" Then
    .Sheets("Parts List").Cells(i, 3).Value = .Sheets("Product Description").Cells(i, 2).Value
End If
Next i
End With
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. I'm really just trying to get it to loop through this one sheet and extract things and put them on another sheet. Sounds easy enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a few minor changes to your code, mainly to keep a counter of which row you are writing to on the destination sheet, plus quite a few cosmetic changes:

```
Dim srcRow As Long
Dim dstRow As Long

Dim srcWs As Worksheet
Dim dstWs As Worksheet

Set srcWs = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Product Description")
Set dstWs = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Parts List")
dstRow = 9  'Initially point to the header row

'Only do your For loop for cells that contain a product code, rather than
'for the 1 million rows in the worksheet
For srcRow = 1 To srcWs.Range("A" & srcWs.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    '.Sheets("Parts List").Range("A1").Select  'Not needed
    If dstWs.Cells(dstRow, "A").Value <> srcWs.Cells(srcRow, "A") Then
        'Increment destination row
        dstRow = dstRow + 1
        'Store part number
        dstWs.Cells(dstRow, "A").Value = srcWs.Cells(srcRow, "A").Value
    End If
    'Store other data
    Select Case srcWs.Cells(srcRow, "B").Value
        Case "DES"
            dstWs.Cells(dstRow, "B").Value = srcWs.Cells(srcRow, "C").Value
        Case "EXT"
            dstWs.Cells(dstRow, "E").Value = srcWs.Cells(srcRow, "C").Value
        Case "MKT"
            dstWs.Cells(dstRow, "C").Value = srcWs.Cells(srcRow, "C").Value
    End Select
Next
```

---

The "Next without a For" error that you were getting was due to an unmatched `If` statement (your first `If` statement had no corresponding `End If`) and your `With` block started inside your `For` loop but finished after the loop ended.  That type of error is easily picked up by always / consistently indenting your code.  Below is what your original code looked like once it was indented:

```
Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To Rows.Count
    With ActiveWorkbook
        .Sheets("Parts List").Range("A1").Select
        If .Sheets("Parts List").Cells(i, 1).Value = .Sheets("Product Description").Cells(i, 1) Then
            If .Sheets("Product Description").Cells(i, 2).Value = "DES" Then
                .Sheets("Parts List").Cells(i, 2).Value = .Sheets("Product Description").Cells(i, 2).Value
            ElseIf .Sheets("Product Description").Cells(i, 2).Value = "EXT" Then
                .Sheets("Parts List").Cells(i, 5).Value = .Sheets("Product Description").Cells(i, 2).Value
            ElseIf .Sheets("Product Description").Cells(i, 2).Value = "MKT" Then
                .Sheets("Parts List").Cells(i, 3).Value = .Sheets("Product Description").Cells(i, 2).Value
            End If
        'Notice that the Next i is not lined up with the For i
        Next i
    End With
'Notice that we haven't ended up back at the left - so we must be missing
'the end of some sort of "block"
```

Comment: Hmmm...This is getting closer (and considerably neater than my original). This takes the part number and moves it over correctly but the other columns don't show anything more than the description code.
Part 1, DES, MKT, " ", EXT // 
Part 2, DES, MKT, " ", EXT // 
Part 3, DES, MKT, " ", EXT // 

and so on.

Comment: @Frethy - Sorry, I didn't notice you were writing column B instead of column C (and I just copy/pasted much of your code) - edited the answer to point to column C instead.  (The edit is just to change the "2" to a "3" when copying the data across.)

Comment: @Frethy - I made yet another edit - to change the column references from numbers to letters.  It will slow the execution down **slightly** but will make it clearer which columns are being referred to.

Comment: Yes. This is perfect. @YowE3K this is perfect. Thank you.